# Bus Error(Core Dumped) Scrapy, on an ubuntu machine

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to gather the data from bitcointalk.org about users and their public bitcoin keys and I am using Scrapy for this purpose, now within a week after starting my experiments I am always running into "Bus Error(Core Dumped)", I fail to understand why. I am guessing there might be some error with my Scrapy settings, I am running behind on my research work and could really use some help. Below is my code for my settings file:

```
BOT_NAME = 'tutorial'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorial.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorial.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'tutorial.pipelines.TutorialPipeline': 100, }
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 4
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeue.FifoMemoryQueue'
```

Here is the link to the public repository , I have uploaded the entire code for you to have a lookt at github.com/Nikhil1810/ScrapyBitcointalk.git

Comment: AFAIK `Bus Error` means your machine had trouble connecting/reading/writing to your ssd/hdd, so it's not related to scrapy at all. In general you probably don't want to have week long spider runs and you should split that in multiple jobs if possible or if it is a continuous scrape restart the job every once in a while.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870353/bus-error-system-error

Comment: @Granitosaurus: How to restart the scrape if its a continuous one, because I want my scrape to continue from the same page and keep on proceeding. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't not in any easy, worth-while way. Common way is to split your crawler in small batches of few thoudand items so you can restart the whole batch if something happens.